# How I can pass environment variables to scss/ sass file using laravel mix and webpack?

Tags: laravel, webpack, webpack-4, laravel-mix, scss-lint

I have an environment variable CDN_URL and I want to send this variable to the SCSS file.
I am also tried prependData of sass-loader.

I have to use Laravel 5.7, Laravel Mix 4.1.2 and webpack 4.27.1

error: Invalid CSS after "...load the styles": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"

Below is my 'webpack.mix.js' file code.

```
mix.webpackConfig({
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
            use: [
                'vue-style-loader',
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        indentedSyntax: true,
                        prependData: '$cdn-s3-static-url: ' + process.env.CDN_S3_STATIC_URL + ';',
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
},
```

});

Below is my '_functions.scss' file code:

```
@function asset($type, $file) {
 @return url('#{$cdn-s3-static-url}#{$asset-base-path}#{$type}/#{$file}');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was running a gatsby site.  Before each build, it runs gatsby-config.js, which has access to environment variables.

So at the top of the .js file that builds, before module.exports, I put this:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  fs.writeFileSync('./src/styles/build-style.scss','$root: "/development-path/";');
} else {
  fs.writeFileSync('./src/styles/build-style.scss','$root: "/production-path/";');
}
```

This results in a file which looks like:

```
$root: "/development-path/";
```

Then in the SCSS files where I needed ENV-dependent behaviour, I have:

```
@import './build-style.scss';
@font-face {
  font-family: "MyFontFamily";
  src: url($root + "font/MyFontFamily.woff") format('woff');
}
```

And now my asset (font in this example) loads from different spots depending on my dev/production environment variable.

It feels like a big hack and I'm sure there's a more correct way somewhere, but this got me moving again after an hour stoppage and it is working so far.  I will probably extend it in the future to have `build-style-dev.scss`, `build-style-prod.scss`, and just copy them into `build-style.scss` at compile time.  Or research the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepend data to SASS using [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#prependdata)

For example to pass the `CDN_URL` from `.env`

Extend `webpack.mix.js`

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              prependData: '$env: ' + process.env.CDN_URL + ';',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: I use this but I am getting below error:
Invalid CSS after "...load the styles": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"

I have use Laravel 5.7, Laravel Mix 4.1.2 and webpack webpack 4.27.1.

Comment: We can't tell if you don't include your SASS file

Comment: _functions.scss:
```
@function asset($type, $file) {
 @return url('#{$cdn-s3-static-url}#{$asset-base-path}#{$type}/#{$file}');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may inject environment variables into Laravel Webpack Mix by prefixing a key in your .env file with MIX_. After the variable has been defined in your .env file, you may access via the `process.env` object.

So in your example, you should create a new variable in .env file like MIX_CDN_URL and inside `webpack.mix.js` you can access it using

```
process.env.MIX_CDN_URL
```

You can [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#prependdata) that will achieve the results you desire.

Comment: process is a nodejs thing, OP is looking for a way to pass it to SASS not Javascript